# rewriting a function using es2018 syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i wrote a function called startFrom that takes 2 numbers start and length and returns an array with a length of "length" starting with "start" so startFrom(5, 3); would return [5, 6, 7]; and i wrote another function called goUntil that does the same thing but in reverse so goUntil(5, 3); would return [3, 4, 5]; here's the code

```
const startFrom = (start, length) => {
    let result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result.push(i);
        result[i] += start;
    }
    return result;
}
const goUntil = (end, length) => {
    let secondResult = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        secondResult.push(i);
    }
    for (var i = secondResult.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        secondResult[i] = end;
        end--;
    }
    return secondResult;
}
```

there's nothing wrong with it works just fine i'm just wondering if i can rewrite this code more concise using es018 syntax

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. This is off topic at SO - perhaps at codereview it will fare better

Comment: https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/create-range-0...n-easily-using-one-line/

Comment: There's nothing specific to ES2018 that would benefit this code, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concise this code using `Array.from()` method:

```js
const startFrom = (start, length) => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => (start + i));

const goUntill = (end, length) => Array.from(
                                    { length }, (_, i) => (end - (length - (i + 1)))
                                  );

console.log(startFrom(5, 3));
console.log(goUntill(5, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `Array.from` is an ES2015 addition, not ES2018.

Comment: Also, the result of this `goUntil` doesn't match OP's output. (It's reversed.) This can be corrected by replacing the lambda operation with `end - (length - i - 1)`

Comment: @Abion47 Thanks for the input. I just noticed and corrected the calculation.